# pass value from aspx to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have set of addresses, which i use to load on the map,

im loading those addresses from cs file to javascript using HiddenField like

```
//  In code behind   
string []arr=new string[]
{
"51.482238,0.001581",
"51.473364,0.011966","51.471974,-0.000651",
"51.472108,-0.002196","51.474995,-0.003827",
"51.476492,-0.005629","51.477855,-0.006058",
"51.478443,-0.007045","51.479298,-0.007861",
"51.481202,-0.002136","51.481577,-0.0022"
};

    for ( int j = 0; j < arr.Length ; j++ )
    {
        HiddenField1.Value += arr[j] + ":";
    }
}

//in javascript

var hidValue= document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>").value;

var latlonArr = hidValue.split(':');
for (var i = 0; i < latlonArr.length - 1; i++) 
    {
        //alert("item :"+ i + " : "+latlonArr[i]);
        var latlonA = latlonArr[i].split(',');
        var latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(latlonA[0],latlonA[1]);
        arrCoords.push(latlon);
    }
```

so, now if i have more no. of address, will it be okay to go with HiddenField for addresses ranging from 100 to 1000 or more..

Comment: you can try to load these addresses using Web-Services and AJAX.

Comment: @ebramtharwat like ? (im relatively new to those concepts)

Comment: actually i load addresses from db table ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the performance with the maximum number of addresses you might have, if the performance is OK then you should be fine.
If the performance is not OK then consider fetching the addresses asynchronusly, e.g. 100 at a time.

Comment: if thatz the case then i might go for another hiddenfield (almost 1/100) rit?

Answer (score 0):

In code-behind you can use:

```
string []arr=new string[]
{
   "51.482238,0.001581",
   "51.473364,0.011966","51.471974,-0.000651",
   "51.472108,-0.002196","51.474995,-0.003827",
   "51.476492,-0.005629","51.477855,-0.006058",
   "51.478443,-0.007045","51.479298,-0.007861",
   "51.481202,-0.002136","51.481577,-0.0022"
};
HiddenField1.Value = arr.join(",");
```